# Issues querying SQL database with dplyr in R

Tags: mysql, r, dplyr

I'm brand new to dplyr and I'm having issues querying my SQL database using the package.

I have three tables: report, flight, and condition.  report connects to flight through the column flight_id and flight connects to condition through the column condition_id.  What I'm attempting to do is get a count of all rows once these three tables are joined where the values in the column conditions_precipitation of the condition table is equal to "Fog", "Fog, Rain", "Fog, Rain, Snow", or "Fog, Snow".

I've attempted the following code to get the count, but it isn't working correctly, and I think that there is a small problem somewhere that I am overlooking:

```
tbl(mydb, "report") %>%
  inner_join(tbl(mydb, "flight"), by = "flight_id") %>%
  inner_join(tbl(mydb, "condition"), by = "condition_id") %>%
  filter("conditions_precipitation" %in% c("Fog", "Fog, Rain", "Fog, Rain, Snow", "Fog, Snow")) %>%
  summarize(n())
```

This outputs:

```
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
# Database: sqlite 3.19.3
#   [/path/to/database]
  `n()`
  <int>
1     0
```

I know that this isn't correct, so I'm wondering where my problem is.

Comment: Is "conditions_precipitation" the name of a column? Try remove "" and use conditions_precipitation. Notice that `dplyr` uses non-standard evaluation.

Comment: This was the problem, thanks you.  Can you elaborate on why the quotes aren't needed for columns but they are for tables?

Comment: I am glad this helps. You can search for any tutorials about `dplyr` to see how non-standard evaluation works.

Comment: The filter function doesn't need any double quotes. You generally use `table$column`. But as you're chaining it on the way, the table name isn't reqd. So, just the column name. With that syntax, we don't use double quotes.